# Switchport and default config

Tags: cisco-commands

Is there any functional difference between entered switchport and default interface commands.

I configured PIM on an interface.

If I do `switchport` and `no switchport pim` command is existing.
is this expected behavior?

Suppose after entering the `pim` command, if I default that interface, I am not seeing that configuration.

Is this expected behavior?

Device: Catalyst 3K

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What specific device are you referring to?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you default an interface, it will remove all non-default commands.

If you configure a non-default command, such as configuring PIM, on an interface, reverting the interface to its default will remove the non-default PIM configuration.

That is the expected behavior.